# Do Chromebooks offer adequate offline programability?

Tags: chromebook

Do Chromebooks offer adequate programming capabilities offline?
I can never guarantee my WiFi access.

I know I can access local files, and being Linux-based, what does this mean for programming offline?

Also, I am returning to obtain my MSc in IT. Would this be a good purchase for such a cause? I am focusing on web development (HTML, JavaScript, Rails).

I want to know specifically if a Chromebook (I have my eyes on the Acer C720) can get the work done. True, I'll probably rare ever be offline, but I want to know if I'll be able to both edit code, then run it to troubleshoot.

My main points: editing and running code on a Chromebook. Also, could I amend the drawback by running Windows or Linux (ie, Ubuntu, Mint)?Thanks guys for any advice.

Comment: a quick search found this: http://www.chromebookhq.com/five-best-online-ides-making-the-switch-to-a-chromebook/

Answer (score 0):

I use an Acer C720 Chromebook (2GB RAM, 16GB SSD) as my Meteor (Javascript, HTML. CSS, MongoDB) development machine. The specs may sound poor but in reality - thanks to the fantastic Haswell chip - the laptop is great.

I have Xubuntu installed instead of ChromeOS... so maybe that is not a real answer to your question.

It's a fantastic little machine - long battery life and boots in a few seconds. I tried Bodhi Linux first but find Xubuntu better for my needs.

I expanded the storage using a keep-in tiny UltraFit 64GB USB 3.0 flash key. Amazing device.

I use an HDMI monitor when doing longer coding sessions.

Device cost me $150 on eBay and around $25 for the USB key.

I use the free http://komodoide.com/komodo-edit/ as my editor.

If you feel like taking the plunge and converting from ChromeOS to Xubuntu, these two links may help:

1. BIOS changes: https://blogs.fsfe.org/the_unconventional/2014/09/19/c720-coreboot/
2. Xubuntu distribution: https://www.distroshare.com/distros/get/14/

Good luck and enjoy!